# Verify copied data between Windows & Linux shares?

Tags: linux, file, verify, integrity, robocopy

I just copied a ton of data from a machine running Windows 7 Ultimate to a server running Ubuntu Server LTS 10.04.  I used the robocopy utility via PowerShell to accommplish this task, but I couldn't find any informaiton online regarding whether Robocopy verifies the copied file's integrity once it is copied to the server.

First of all, does anyone know if this is done inherently?  There is no switch that explicitly allows you to add verification to a file transfer.

Second, if it doesn't or there is uncertainty about whether or not it does, what would be the simplest method to accomplish this for multiple directories with several files/sub-directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest mechanism I know would rely on an [`md5sum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) and [Unix-like `find`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) utility on your Windows machine.

You can generate a manifest file of filenames / md5sums:

```
find /source -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > MD5SUM
```

Copy the `MD5SUM` file to your Linux machine, and then run:

```
cd /path/to/destination
md5sum --quiet -c MD5SUM
```

You'll get a list of files that fail:

```
$ md5sum --quiet -c /tmp/MD5SUM 
/etc/aliases: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 1 of 341 computed checksums did NOT match
```

Comment: Do you know of such a program for Windows?

Comment: I can get this to work going from Linux to Windows, but not the other way around.  Most Windows utilities seem to output the data with a carriage return, whereas md5sum doesn't.  Creates tons of problems when creating a checksum on the Windows system and verifying on Linux.  I tried passing the -b option, but apparently you can only do that when creating the md5sums.

Comment: Ah. You can remove the carriage returns on Linux with `tr -d '\r' < input > output`. (`tr(1)` does character translations and with `-d` deletions. The `'\r'` is the escape sequence for the CR character.)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier method is to use unix uilities **diff** and **rsync**

With diff you can compare two file but you can compare also two directories. With diff I would recomend this command:

```
diff -r source/directory/ destination/directory
```

-r    forces diff to analyse directorysor recursively

The second option is to use rsync which is ment to sync files or directories but with **-n** option you can use it also to analyes differencies between directories. rsync also  works even when the files are not on the same host it means on one there can be remote host and you can acess it even with ssh. Pluss rsync is really flexible with its meny options avaialbe

```
rsync -avn --itemize-changes --progress --stats source/directory/ destination/directory/
```

- -n                                   *option makes rsync do a "dry-run", meaning it makes no changes on the*
- -a       *otion includes in it "Recursive mode,symbolic links,file permissions, file timestamps, file owner parameter, file group paratmeter*
- -v                                   *increase verbosity*
- --itemize-changes          *output a change-summary for all updates*

Here you can find even more ways how to compear directories:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/12473/file-and-directory-comparison-tool

On **rsync** wikipedia page you can find windows alternative programs for **rsync**